# What is the difference between these two Html statements?

Tags: asp.net, html

What is the difference between these two Html statements.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgHelp"  ImageUrl="~/images/help.gif" />
```

&

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgHelp"  ImageUrl="/images/help.gif" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One image path is **absolute** (~/images/help.gif) and one is **relative** (/images/help.gif)

Answer (score 2):

Their path to image differs.

[This one is a nice overview](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/132081.aspx) of how to handle asp.net paths:

> ~/ Root Relative Paths and ResolveUrl() and ResolveClientUrl()
>
> ASP.NET supports root-relative virtual path syntax in most of its URL properties in Web Forms.
>   So you can easily specify a root relative path in a control rather than a location relative path: